# Can't connect to AWS DB from locally-hosted Node.js app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure

I'm running a locally-hosted (i.e. on my machine) Node.js app and am trying to connect it to a remote AWS-hosted Postgres DB.

My app is an Azure Function and looks like this:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
    host: '*******.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    user: '********',
    password: '************',
    database: '************',
    ssl: true
})
client.connect();
module.exports = async (ctx, req) => {
    //...todo
}
```

When I run it, via `func start`, I get this:

[image]

If I take Azure out of the equation, and just run the script manually, via

```
node path/to/script/js
```

...I instead get:

[image]

If I set `ssl` to `false` and run as above, I get:

[image]

The credentials are definitely correct. If I use the same credentials to connect to the DB via a DB client such as Heidi SQL or DBeaver, it connects fine. It even connects from my locally-running Rails app. So something is preventing Node from connecting to it.

Possibly related: I have tried to set up an API Connection within the Azure Portal to my DB and that fails to connect also.

There is nothing I can see on the AWS DB itself to suggest why this should happen, but I'm no server admin so perhaps there's some security setting I need to change.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've `ssl: true` in your client connection config. The pg client tries to establish a secure SSL/TLS connection with the remote database. But, for AWS RDS instances you need to supply additional configurations for SSL to work. That's why the error. You can go through the guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html) to know more about how SSL works with RDS instances.

To summarize, you need to pass `ssl` field as an object instead of just `true` providing the `pem`/`cer` file in the `ca` field. Depending upon the region where your AWS RDS instance is hosted, you can download the `pem`/`cer` file from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html).

Then you can pass the file as the parameter using `fs`. See example below:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Client({
    host: 'aws_rds_host',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'my_username',
    password: 'my_pass',
    database: 'my_db',
    ssl: {        
        ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/pem/file').toString()
    }
})
client.connect();
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'll try that. Why would this not be a factor when connecting to the same remote DB via other means, e.g. via my Rails backend (connects to it fine) or a client like Heidi or DBeaver (ditto)? Why does SSL need this config when accessed over Node but not other means?

Comment: There's a flag in node-pg `rejectUnauthorized`. If you set this to false, the connection will be established even if there is some problem with ssl. I just checked the connection using DBeaver. In the SSL tab, under `Advanced` section, there are various SSL modes. For modes `verify-ca`, `verify-full` and `blank`, it's not able to connect to the DB. Connection is getting established otherwise. I'm assuming some of the above mentioned flags are set by default in rails which is avoiding ssl connection failure.

Comment: Interesting! Super helpful - thank you.